# Configuration of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for log in

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to configure spring secutiry in my SpringBoot 2 application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/users")
            .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("u")
                        .password("p")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}


@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

**login.mustache**

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
        <input type="text"     name="username" id="username" placeholder="Login" /><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" /><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}">
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

I expect to be redirected to **/users** page. But actually I get error code = 302 and I appear at **/login/error**

**SOLUTION:** I've added @Bean annotation to userDetailsService() and it helped.

Comment: Your username or your password is wrong. Maybe your are using the wrong `UserDetailsService`. Try to add `@Bean` to your `userDetailsService()` method.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expose your `UserDetailsService` as a bean, see [Spring Boot Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-change-the-authenticationmanager-and-add-user-accounts):

> **84.2 Change the AuthenticationManager and Add User Accounts**
>
> If you provide a `@Bean` of type `AuthenticationManager`, `AuthenticationProvider`, or `UserDetailsService`, the default `@Bean` for `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` is not created, so you have the full feature set of Spring Security available (such as various authentication options).
>
> The easiest way to add user accounts is to provide your own `UserDetailsService` bean.

Your modified code:

```java
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
            User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                    .username("u")
                    .password("p")
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```